# Subqueries and Join in SQL

Tags: sql, select, join, inner-join

I was solving the following question where I have to "List all the people who have worked with 'Art Garfunkel'."

The question is no. 16 here : http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/More_JOIN_operations

Edit: I wrote the following code to get the whole names list, but in vain

```
select name 
from actor left join casting on id=actorid
where movieid IN ( select movieid
from casting left join actor on id=actorid
where id IN ( select id from actor where name ='Art Garfunkel'))
```

Kindly tell me where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.name 
FROM actor a 
INNER JOIN casting b ON a.id = b.actorid 
INNER JOIN (SELECT b.movieid FROM casting b 
            INNER JOIN actor c ON b.actorid=c.id AND c.name = 'Art Garfunkel'
           ) c ON b.movieid = c.movieid 
where a.name <> 'Art Garfunkel';
```

Comment: could you tell me where I was missing out form the query I wrote in my question?

Comment: I got the ids alright but now I want to go for the names directly, can you tell me how to go about this?

Comment: @Naga Check my updated query I had tested it on your URL It was working

Comment: Yes it works, only one doubt I have is that, you write the sub query after inner join and name the the table as c when you had already named the actor with the alias c, how does this work?

Comment: Saharsh, thanks , I wrote down the code on paper and understood what it means step by step. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need any subqueries for this, you can do it with JOINS only..

```
select distinct c1.name
from movie a 
inner join casting b on a.id=b.movieid
inner join actor c on b.actorid=c.id and c.name = 'Art Garfunkel'
inner join actor c1 on b.actorid=c.id and c.name <> 'Art Garfunkel'
```

Comment: I got the ids alright but now I want to go for the names directly, can you tell me how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   a.name
FROM
   actor a

   INNER JOIN casting c
   ON a.actorID = c.actorID
   AND a.actor <> 'Art Garfunkel'

WHERE
   c.movieID IN

(
SELECT
   m.movieID
FROM
   casting c

   INNER JOIN actor a
   ON c.actorID = a.actorID

   INNER JOIN movie m
   ON m.movieID = c.movieID

WHERE
   a.name = 'Art Garfunkel'
)
```